# Can't Download File in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

I'm developing a store that allows a client to download custom scripts. I've set up the download folder and the Store and my configuration seems to be correct.

```
            {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                <li>{exp:store:download order_id="{order_id}" url="{file_for_sale}"}
                  Download
                {/exp:store:download}</li>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

What happens is I get an error like this:[image: ExpressionEngine Throwback Error]

What is even more confusing is that my original folder path isn't

/homepages/9/d201932266/htdocs/frameexpert/

My original file path is:

/kruden/homepages/9/d201932266/htdocs/frameexpert/

I'm not sure where this file path is coming from. I've scoured all the config files to see if this is one of the directories, but it isn't.

Any insights would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Store are you running? What is the 'Server Path to Upload Directory' set to under Content > Files > File Upload Preferences?

Comment: Expresso Store 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bug I discovered. Whether or not this is just a problem specific to the server I'm using or just a downright mistake in the Expresso Store 2.2.0 code I'm yet to be determined.

My settings:
-Server Path to Upload Directory: /homepages/9/d201932266/htdocs/frameexpert/images/page_images/

I Edited this file: store/src/store/service/StoreService.php

```
public function get_file_path($file_id)
{
    $path = ee()->db->where('file_id', $file_id)
        ->get('files')->row('rel_path');

    if (empty($path)) return FALSE;

    // is this a relative path?
    if (strpos($path, '/') !== 0) {

        //Note: Detected Bug in Expresso Store. The '../' doesn't bring us far enough
        //back. APPPATH returns '/direct_path_to_ee/frameexpert/expressionengine/system/'
        //What this line of code returns is 
        //'/direct_path_to_ee/frameexpert/expressionengine/system/../frameexpert/images/page_images/file.zip'

        $path = APPPATH.'../'.$path;
    }

    return $path;
}
```

What is happening here is that the 'get_file_path()' function returns an incorrect path. All I did to fix this was:

```
    // is this a relative path?
    if (strpos($path, '/') !== 0) {

        //Note: Changed '../' to '../../../'
        $path = APPPATH.'../../../'.$path;
    }
```

This resolved my issue.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing core files and this shouldn't be necessary. You didn't provide an answer to Adrian's question above regarding your file upload preferences but I'm fairly sure that is where you problem lies. Check your [File Upload Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#upload-destination-edit-label) and ensure they point to the right location. You can use absolute or relative paths.

Comment: What I found is that the problem isn't with my direct server path. The problem is with the APPPATH constant that is set to go to the '(home directory)/expressionengine/system/' and my download folder lives in (home directory).

Comment: Another solution would be to place my download folder into '/expressionengine/'

Comment: Pretty sure this is already fixed in the latest version (2.3.1). If you can test and let us know it would be useful.